# Need to import python file into Robot file

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to call Python file from Robot file where I am getting error as

on line 2: Importing library 'Custom_lib.CustomLib' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module
named 'Custom_lib'

Below is content of my "Custom_lib.py" file,

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword

class Custom_lib:

        ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'

        @keyword
        def get_my_message(self):
                word = "Hello World"
                return word
```

This is "my.robot" file,

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Custom_lib.py


 
*** Test Cases ***
call python
    ${SEARCH}   =   Get My Message
    log  ${SEARCH}
```

when I try to run my robot file with the command : robot my.robot

Importing library 'Custom_lib.CustomLib' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module
named 'Custom_lib'

can anyone please help me to resolve this, really apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your code and it worked, as long as `Custom_lib.py` is in the same directory of `my.robot`. Only needed to remove spacing at keyword call:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Custom_lib.py

*** Test Cases ***
call python
    ${SEARCH}=    Get My Message
    log    ${SEARCH}
```